# Spring without xml configuration is not scanning packages

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I can't figure out how to setup Spring without XML to scan packages and inject components.

I have the following code.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mypackage")
public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    }
}


@Service
public class Foo {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("FOO");
    }
}

@Controller
public class FooController {

    private Foo foo;

    @Autowired
    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

And the following pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org-springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org-springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

`Foo` class and `FooController` are under the `com.mypackage` package but the code never hits `setFoo`.

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Spring isn't *actually* magic. Your `main` method just falls off the end instead of starting a Spring container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the ApplicationContext first. If you are using Spring Boot, it takes care of it. It's useful especially for starting points.

Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-instantiating-container).

Comment: Yep that was the part missing. Thank you very much